# Text affecting positioning

Tags: html, css

I have created a div to contain stuff. Inside of these divs I have divs, I have other divs nested. When I put text in these nested divs it moves the top of the parent div down. Like it's giving it a margin, but there isn't one. I've tried removing all padding and margins, along with formatting the text. You can see what I mean by this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bL0af5ac/).

```css
.artworkShowcase #artworkDisplay{
  width:calc(100% - 14px);
  margin:7px;
  height:80%;
  background-color:#FFF; 
  border-radius:5px;
}

.artworkShowcase{
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#34495e;
  width:calc(100% / 3 - 34px);
  height:250px;
  border-radius:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="artworkShowcase">
  <div id="artworkDisplay"></div>
  <div id="aTitle">TITLE</div>
  <div id="aPrice">PRICE</div>
</div>
<div class="artworkShowcase"></div>
```

Comment: Are you saying only side portions should have margin and no margin on top? http://jsfiddle.net/bL0af5ac/2/

Comment: @TheUknown No, I ment that if you can see on the left div, it's a bit lower than the div on the right. They are supposed to be the same height. If you want try taking out the text on the left div and it will be even with the other div. It's something to do with the text.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bL0af5ac/3/ that display: inline-block is strange (it causes unwanted margins/spaces: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/, not sure if this is the problem, in this particular case),  when you populate second div with content, everything is ok? :)

Comment: Evidence: http://jsfiddle.net/eaxL88ef/ i've changed display to block, and added float - problem disappears... So, inline-block is cause, don't know why, i would like explanation, too :)

Comment: lol, Never mind @nevermind also came up with same solution

Comment: @Unknown, yes... :) These strange little things causes that i still prefer display:block and float, even if i need clearfix... :)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add css rule to make the div float left. This happens because it contains other divs inside. If you add same code to both the divs they will be aligned correctly. Check out the corrected code below. Run the snippet and it should work fine. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bL0af5ac/4/), just in case.

```css
.artworkShowcase #artworkDisplay{
  width:calc(100% - 14px);
  margin:7px;
  height:80%;
  background-color:#FFF; 
  border-radius:5px;
}

.artworkShowcase{
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#34495e;
  width:calc(100% / 3 - 34px);
  height:250px;
  border-radius:5px;
  float:left;
  margin:2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="artworkShowcase">
  <div id="artworkDisplay"></div>
  <div id="aTitle">TITLE</div>
  <div id="aPrice">PRICE</div>
</div>
<div class="artworkShowcase"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the default vertical alignment of `inline-block`s is along their baseline (which is the last line of text OR the lower border, if the DIV contains no text).  Just add  `vertical align: top;` to `.artworkShowcase` , this will do what you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/kwj0cetL/1/